# Full screen - Browser JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser

I have a script in js that lets me switch to full screen mode on my browser.  I have a problem, if I change the page or reload the page, the full screen is removed.
How can I keep the full screen mode even if I change or reload the page?

Thank you

```
function openFullscreen() {
  if (elem.requestFullscreen) {
    elem.requestFullscreen();
  } else if (elem.mozRequestFullScreen) { /* Firefox */
    elem.mozRequestFullScreen();
  } else if (elem.webkitRequestFullscreen) { /* Chrome, Safari and Opera */
    elem.webkitRequestFullscreen();
  } else if (elem.msRequestFullscreen) { /* IE/Edge */
    elem.msRequestFullscreen();
  }
}
```

Comment: “*I have a problem*” - and what is your “*problem*”?

Comment: Once the browser has been made full screen simply refreshing the page will not force it back to standard. I'd check your code to ensure you're not re-setting it yourself

Answer (score 0):

When the page loads you can fire a document.ready event

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // make fullscreen
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just send a `${document}.ready(function() { // make full screen here })` request, inside that make it go fullscreen, so it'll auto do it when you change pages

Answer (score -1):

First add a `<script src>` to your html for jquery. Then inside your javascript file/tag, add `document.ready()` and put your code inside it.

Example with your code:

### Adding Jquery to HTML

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
```

It's adviced to use the script from here for security integrity: https://code.jquery.com/

### Your JS

Your js should look like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    openFullscreen();
});

function openFullscreen() {
  if (elem.requestFullscreen) {
    elem.requestFullscreen();
  } else if (elem.mozRequestFullScreen) { /* Firefox */
    elem.mozRequestFullScreen();
  } else if (elem.webkitRequestFullscreen) { /* Chrome, Safari and Opera */
    elem.webkitRequestFullscreen();
  } else if (elem.msRequestFullscreen) { /* IE/Edge */
    elem.msRequestFullscreen();
  }
}
```

What the above will do is, call your full screen function when the document is loaded. You can do this without jquery as well and add event listeners in JS, but this is easier to understand.

EDIT: JQuery has to be imported before the javascript code! Import Jquery just before starting other  at the end of the page, for performance.